# function or associated item not found for image::ImageBuffer::from_vec()

Tags: image, rust, rust-piston

I'm using Piston's `image` crate, with this code:

```
use image::{Rgb, ImageBuffer, Pixel};

let image = Vec::<Rgb<u8>>::new();

let image_buffer = ImageBuffer::<Rgb<u8>, Vec<Rgb<u8>>>::from_vec(
    width, height
    image,
).unwrap();
```

However I get this error:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `from_vec` found for type `image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgb<u8>, std::vec::Vec<image::Rgb<u8>>>` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:348:21
    |
348 |     let image_buffer = ImageBuffer::<Rgb<u8>, Vec<Rgb<u8>>>::from_vec(
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgb<u8>, std::vec::Vec<image::Rgb<u8>>>`
```

I can't work out why. It's clearly in [the documentation](https://docs.rs/image/0.20.1/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html#method.from_vec), and the types seem right as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding a bit: In the example above, we have a `ImageBuffer::<Rgb<u8>, Vec<Rgb<u8>>`. And `ImageBuffer` provides two implementations of `from_vec`, depending on its type parameters:

```
impl<P, Container> ImageBuffer<P, Container>
where
    P: Pixel<Subpixel = u8> + 'static,
    Container: Deref<Target = [u8]>,
```

```
impl<P: Pixel + 'static> ImageBuffer<P, Vec<P::Subpixel>>
where
    P::Subpixel: 'static,
```

Neither of these worked here because the `Container` parameter type in `ImageBuffer<Rgb<u8>, Vec<Rgb<u8>>` is a vector of `Rgb<u8>` values. It will dereference to a slice of `[Rgb<u8>]`, making it incompatible with the first implementation, and the second one expects a vector of subpixel values ([`<P as Pixel>::Subpixel`](https://docs.rs/image/0.20.0/image/trait.Pixel.html)) rather than actual pixel values (`Rgb<u8>`). This is generally what the `ImageBuffer` type in this crate expects as its pixel data container.

Working example:

```
extern crate image;

use image::{ImageBuffer, Pixel, Rgb};

fn main() {
    let width = 64;
    let height = 64;
    let image = vec![0x7F_u8; width as usize * height as usize * 3];

    let image_buffer =
        ImageBuffer::<Rgb<u8>, Vec<u8>>::from_vec(width, height, image).unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=e03819050adcb81a2e7979de65bc3eb3)

Answer (score 0):

Ah it has to be a `Vec<P::Subpixel>`, i.e. `Vec<u8>` rather than a `Vec<Rgb<u8>>`. That is a little annoying.